# Using media queries in CSS

Tags: css, media-queries, shopify, shopify-template

I'm working on a Shopify theme and wanted to add a media query to only the carousel images when viewport is under 1024px. Right now the images are 100% width and height and cropping on the left and right. I don't want the image to crop so I don't want to apply anything to the height.

This is the code from the theme:

```
.objFit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-position: center;
    object-position: center;
    font-family: 'object-fit: cover;object-position:center;';
  }
}
```

And this is what I'm assuming I should add.

```
@media(max-width: 1023px) {
.objFit {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-position: center;
    object-position: center;
    font-family: 'object-fit: cover;object-position:center;';
  }
}
}
```

I tried to switch the height and width so width came first but it broke the carousel.

I can't seem to get the preview to work to test my code so wanted to ask here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the `height: 100%` on both elements. Simply change `cover` to `contain` in your media query. You also do not need to repeat rules that remain the same in your media query.

I added two examples, one for a landscape orientation image and the other for portrait, so you can see what happens.

Here is the documentation on `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.objFit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .objFit img {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="objFit">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300">
</div>

<div class="objFit">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x900">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for without knowing I was looking for it... if that makes sense.

Comment: @user3634131 great! If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted for future visitors.